# My wife wants a 4th child but I don't

Tags: pregnancy

We currently have a 3-year-old daughter and twin 2-year-old boys.  We are both 32 years old and have decent jobs.

I have many reservations on having another child, but my wife does not seem to want to listen to the reasons I have these reservations, she only says she doesn't feel like she is done yet.

Some of my concerns are as follows:

1. Cost of Daycare (already pay $23,000/year)
2. New house we built last year would not be big enough.
3. Need different vehicles to fit 4 kids
4. When they are older we will have to choose who's events we can go to and who to disappoint
5. Cost of school when they are older
6. Not having enough time with each of the kids to make them feel special
7. Not having any adult time
8. Very hard to find baby sitter for 3 under three, it would be worse for 4.
9. My personal sanity (I have 2 jobs and no time to myself already)
10. Strain on our relationship (feel like roommates sometime instead of husband/wife)

I could add quite a few more but I think you get the idea.

Please any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: read my answer at the question here - https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/my-wife-wants-a-4th-baby-but-i-dont/14495#14495